# onBlur/onFocus not registering at the right time in internet explorer only

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onblur, onfocus

I'm working on making a custom text input field and I'm having trouble with the single line inputs showing up in internet explorer 10 (have not checked other versions). When you click on the text input, it does onFocus which should swap the input background from an image that says "Type name here" to a more blank image that a user can type on top of. And the javascript checks to see if the input is blank, and if it is then onBlur will switch it back to the "Type name here" image, otherwise it will stay on the more blank image.

This all works dandy in all browsers except internet explorer. If you click on the input (and do not move the cursor), it changes the background properly, but then when you hit a button to start typing it switches the background back to "Type name here" and you end up having text on top of text.

I know this is probably hard to imagine so feel free to look at the problem here www.cutephilosophy.com/contact&stuff.php.

It seems as if the problem is that internet explorer thinks "Focus" and "Blur" should be activated differently than other browsers (of course they're doing their own thing..). Does anyone know how I can get around this problem? I've tried onClick instead of onFocus and it's identical, i've also tried forcing it to do things on mouseout or mouseover in order to brute force the problem but nothing seemed to work.

```
<---------- CSS -------------------------------->
    .nameDiv{
        height:59px;
        width:582px;
        background:url("images/contact/nameField.gif");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: left top;
    }
    .nameInput{
        background:transparent;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        border:none;
        width:235px;
        height:59px;
        outline:none;
        background-color:transparent;
        font-family: 'avenirheavy';
        font-size:21px;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        padding-left:95px;
        padding-bottom:5px;
    }

<----------JAVASCRIPT-------------------------------->
    function nameSwap(image){
     var nameInput = document.getElementById('nameInput');
        if(nameInput.value == ""){
          nameInput.style.background = "url(images/contact/"+image+")";
        }
    }

<----------HTML TEXT FIELD --------------------------------> 
        <input name="nameInput" type="text" class="nameInput" id="nameInput" onfocus="nameSwap('nameFieldType.gif')" onblur="nameSwap('nameField.gif')"/>
```